# What is the meaning of "encoding error" in the vsnprintf documentation?

Tags: c++, printf

In the [C++ online docs for vsnprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsnprintf/), it is stated

```
 If an encoding error occurs, a negative number is returned.
```

What does "encoding error" mean in this context, and can an example of such an error be given?

Comment: It probably is referring to character encoding errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is referring to string encoding errors as grinch pointed out. We can reproduce a negative return value with this code, because 129 is an invalid wide character in the Japanese (932) code page when calling `wctomb`:

```
int call_vsnprintf(char* buf, int max, char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

#pragma warning (suppress : 4996)
    int result = vsnprintf(buf, max, format, args);

    va_end(args);

    return result;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".932");
    char dest[100];
    wchar_t wbuf[2];
    wbuf[0] = 129;
    wbuf[1] = 0;

    //this will be -1
    int result = call_vsnprintf(dest, sizeof(dest), "%ls", wbuf);
}
```

Note: This was on Windows, but if it's not portable, it can be fixed easily by searching Asian codepages for widechars that force wctomb to return -1.

Thanks to [James Kuyper on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.std.c/lIvkxXr5_wE/aVuIpm52ToQJ) for pretty much the entire answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me confirm on Debian Millie Smith answer:

```
char dest[100];
wchar_t wbuf[2];
wbuf[0] = 129;
wbuf[1] = 0;
int result = snprintf(dest, sizeof(dest), "%ls", wbuf);
```

result is -1.